# OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails project but `omniauth-linkedin-oauth2` would't work! I have an error like below.

```
   Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

*apps/controllers/omniauth_controller.rb*

```
    class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
        def facebook
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra"))

            if @user.persisted?
                sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
            else
                session["devise.user_attributes"] = @user.attributes
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        end

        def linkedin
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra"))

            if @user.persisted?
                sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
            else
                session["devise.user_attributes"] = @user.attributes
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        end
    end
```

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin,
    Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:linkedin][:client_id],
    Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:linkedin][:client_secret],
    provider_ignores_state: true
```

Comment: Did you add linkedin to: app/config/initializers/devise.rb?

Comment: Thanks it fixed. But I have faced another problem.